# GCloud AppEngine Cannot ssh into standard instance

Tags: google-app-engine, ssh, gcloud

Trying to ssh into AppEngine instance using cli. I have the right command but not sure how to allow ssh for a standard instance or if this is not possible at all. I am new to Gcloud (AWS Guy). Their documentation is not that good about instance types and what is or isnt allowed. Anyone have any pointers on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: App Engine Standard is a framework for running your code somewhat like a library. There is no OS for you to SSH into. App Engine Flexible runs your code as a container, so you can SSH into your instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not possible to access (via SSH or otherwise) a standard environment instance.

Only the flexible environment instances are accessible, see [Connecting to the instance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/debugging-an-instance#connecting_to_the_instance).

Comment: Thank you for confirming this. That is one of the dumbest product decisions. The last straw for me running my application on GAE. Moving over to AWS.

Answer (score -2):

I had issues like this and I fix them by configuring the ressources in the yaml file. Increase number of CPUs and memory it may help

Comment: Increasing CPU and RAM enables accessing a standard environment instance? Really? How?

Comment: resources:
  cpu: 8
  memory_gb: 8