# SSH Into GAE Standard Environment Instance

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Has GCP made any updates yet that allow you to SSH into your GAE Instance when it's running on a Standard environment? I [see a post from 2+ years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56092486/gcloud-appengine-cannot-ssh-into-standard-instance) saying this is not possible. Is that still so today?

Running in Flex environment ends up being $150/mo, and we have no reason to do that just for SSH access. It seems wild to me that Standard environment would not allow a way to SSH into your machine. Need to confirm before I switch providers that this is not possible

Comment: Since this is a question of - is a feature available or not, I would also recommend posting your question to the app engine forum on Google - https://groups.google.com/g/google-appengine Someone from Google will usually be able to provide an answer.

Comment: Flex is created for that.

Comment: Sadly flex is very expensive for the small rails application that we need to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google App Engine Standard does not support SSH.

SSH requires a server to listen for connections from clients. App Engine Standard does not provide an operating system - only a framework. The SSH protocol is not part of that framework. There are other very popular services such as Cloud Run that also do not support SSH access.

SSH also requires a subsystem to store SSH keys and some form of identity. Those features are also not part of the App Engine Standard framework. Once logged in, SSH requires a command prompt, a set of tools that you can run from the command prompt, etc. Those features would dramatically change the environment.

If you require SSH access, then you will need to choose a service that provides that feature. As that usually requires an OS to support an SSH server, the costs are different.

Comment: Thank you, you are correct. We decided to move off of GAE and use a different service that was more affordable and had more support